# How to generate user entered data into a pdf file

Tags: android, pdf

I was about to start working on an Android app. I have fair experience with 4 different programming languages so coding experience is not a problem. However, its my first time working on an Android app and basically i need to get some sort of understanding on how to generate user entered data into a PDF file. For example, how will i have a user fill a form and then press the submit button which generates a PDF file.

Cheers

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow :). This question is too broad to be answered. Kindly read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Share what have you tried and where are you stuck, so that you get better responses.

Comment: You'd need to find a PDF library.  However requests for library suggestions are off topic here.